# How I can read files in miplib

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

does anybody know how I can read mps file in miplib website? I downloaded them and opened them by ampl but it’s not clear what is constraints!!! In the top of the problems has been written : encoding-iso-8859-1 i don’t know what this mean??? I attached opened file [image]!

Answer (score 1):

MIPLIB problems are provided in (a low level) MPS format. Typically MPS files are fed directly into a solver. There is no good way to reconstruct a nice, indexed AMPL model from an MPS file (basically lots of the structure is lost). It should be possible to create some scalar AMPL representation of an MPS file, but that is of very limited value.